# How to correctly overwrite SQLite table rows with new data?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm making a news app which shows the 10 latest news headlines. When the API returns 10 different news articles they are inserted into the table without removing the current ones, resulting in the amount of data increasing by 10 each time.

So far I have tried to update the rows, which works when the table already has data in.  I have tried to DROP the table and recreate it, which displays nothing...

The only solution I've found is to insert dummy data into the table and overwrite it with the data from the api...   What's the best approach to take?  Please see code below.

dbHelper

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="mytube";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String NEWS_TABLE = "news";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "+NEWS_TABLE +"(title TEXT, desc TEXT, url TEXT)";

    Context context;

    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NEWS_TABLE);
        // Create tables (again)
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Insert into DB

    public void insertIntoDB(String title,String desc,String url){
        Log.d("insert data", "");

        // get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // Create ContentValues to add key
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("title", title);
        values.put("desc", desc);
        values.put("url", url);


        // Insert Data
        db.insert(NEWS_TABLE, null, values);

        // Close DB
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "insert value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.i("", "Insert complete");
    }
    /* Retrive  data from database */
    public List<DatabaseModel> getDataFromDB(){
        List<DatabaseModel> modelList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String query = "select * from "+NEWS_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                DatabaseModel model = new DatabaseModel();
                model.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                model.setDesc(cursor.getString(1));
                model.setUrl(cursor.getString(2));

                modelList.add(model);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


       // Log.d("news data", modelList.toString());


        return modelList;
    }




}
```

Activity

```
public class journeyEntertainment extends AppCompatActivity {

    dbHelper helper;
    List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journey_entertainment);
       /* Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/

        getNews();
        helper = new dbHelper(this);
        dbList= new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();

        dbList = helper.getDataFromDB();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleview);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void getNews(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=927e06d9dddb47ee929c9bb7597777055434";

        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String title = jo.getString("title");
                        String  desc = jo.getString("description");
                        String  url = jo.getString("url");

                        title = title.replaceAll("'", "");
                        desc = desc.replaceAll("'", "");
                        url = url.replaceAll("'", "");





                        helper = new dbHelper(journeyEntertainment.this);
                        helper.insertIntoDB(title, desc, url);


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE the old values with the new ones, instead of INSERTing new rows each time.

Comment: But on first run of the app there would be no values to update.

Comment: You can use **default values** when you create your table.

Comment: Why can't you just delete the old ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add the following method to your `dbHelper` (this will delete all the rows from the table);

```
public void removeAllRowsFromNewsTable(){
    Log.d("insert data", "");

    // get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(NEWS_TABLE,null,null);
}
```

2) In your `getNews` method amend :-

```
                    helper = new dbHelper(journeyEntertainment.this);
                    helper.insertIntoDB(title, desc, url);
```

to :-

```
                    helper = new dbHelper(journeyEntertainment.this);
                    helper.removeAllRowsFromNewsTable();
                    helper.insertIntoDB(title, desc, url);
```

Comment: thanks! I had previously tried something similar, however, that removes everything apart from the first entry in the table

Comment: Cracked it!  moved 'helper.removeAllRowsFromNewsTable();' to just above the for loop... works great now.. Thanks, @MikeT